# componentDidUpdate vs componentWillReceiveProps use case in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is how we use `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.myProp !== this.props.myProps) {
    // nextProps.myProp has a different value than our current prop
  }
}
```

It's very similar to `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.myProps !== this.props.myProp) {
    // this.props.myProp has a different value
    // ...
  }
}
```

I can see some differences, like if I do setState in componentDidUpdate, render will trigger twice, and the argument for componentWillReceiveProps is nextProps, while argument for `componentDidUpdate` is prevProp, but seriously I don't know when to use them. I often use `componentDidUpdate`, but with prevState, like change a dropdown state and call api

eg.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if(prevState.seleted !== this.state.seleted) {
        this.setState({ selected: something}, ()=> callAPI())
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think this can help you https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount there is a list of all life cycle methods

Comment: Without really answering your question  .. [The React team appears to be preparing to deprecate all of the `will` `lifecycle methods`.](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12152) I'd say that's a decent signal to stick with / migrate to the `did` `methods`.

Answer (score 50):

The main difference between the two is:

- When they are called in a component's lifecycle
- How it updates component `state`

### When are they called?

As the names suggest – and as you probably know since you mentioned "if I do setState in componentDidUpdate, render will trigger twice" – `componentDidUpdate` is called *after* the component updates (received new props or state). This is why the parameters to this function is `prevProps` and `prevState`.

So if you wanted to do something *before* the component received new props, you'd use `componentWillReceiveProps`, and if you wanted to do something *after* it received new props or state, you'd use `componentDidUpdate`.

### How do they update `state`?

The main difference here is:

- `componentWillReceiveProps` will update state [synchronously](https://medium.com/@nimelrian/as-of-react-16-you-should-use-componentwillreceiveprops-only-to-update-state-synchronously-as-in-a9d66457c510)
- `componentDidUpdate` will update state [asynchronously](https://medium.com/@nimelrian/as-of-react-16-you-should-use-componentwillreceiveprops-only-to-update-state-synchronously-as-in-a9d66457c510).

This can be important as there are some gotchya's that can come up when trying to sync state with other parts of your component's props.

Comment: what would be some examples of doing things BEFORE the component is updates which can't be done AFTER the component is updated ?