# need to make the api call only if it satisfies the if condition

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

- I neeed to make an api call at two different files.
- In one file i am making an api call inside componentWillMount.`this.props.getBirdsData();`
- but where as in another file I need to make the call only if it satisfies the if condition.

```
    if (
      hardTerm === 'ball' && terms === 'bat' &&
      swmming < running
    ) {
      this.props.getSportsData();
    }
```

- when I make the call inside the if condition, the request is happening multiple times so I am not getting the responses.
- in the first file I am getting data only if I put inside componentWillReceiveProps, cant I get the data using componentDidMount.
- In this link they are telling componentWillReceiveProps will update state synchronously. In file one can you tell how they are doingsynchronously
  [componentDidUpdate vs componentWillReceiveProps use case in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386324/componentdidupdate-vs-componentwillreceiveprops-use-case-in-react/51313510)
  `this.setState({ radioButtonValues: radioButtonValues });`
- providing my relevant code below.
- can you tell me how to fix it

**working file one**

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.initialize(this.state);
    this.props.getRun();
    console.log("step1 componentDidMount this.props--->", this.props);
    this.props.getBirdsData();
    // console.log(" componentDidMount this.props.getBirdsData()--->", this.props.adminRun);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.adminRun.length != nextProps.adminRun.length) {
      let adminRuns = nextProps.adminRun.data.filter(val => val.packageType === "Run");
      const radioButtonValues = adminRuns.map(obj => {
        return { label: obj.ownerCode + obj.subPackageDescription, value: obj.ownerCode };
      });
      this.setState({ radioButtonValues: radioButtonValues });
    }
  }
```

**not working file two**

```
 componentDidMount() {

        this.props.getSportsData();
    }

     renderMoon() {
        const { terms, hardTerm } = this.state;
        const { classes, handleSubmit, handleSkip, handleBack } = this.props;

        let running = moment(new Date());

        if (this.props.form.Page && this.props.form.Page.values) {

            let swmming = moment(this.props.form.Page.values.swmming, "MM/DD/YYYY");

            if (
                hardTerm === 'ball' && terms === 'bat' &&
                swmming < running
            ) {
                // debugger;

                console.log('renderMoon inside if--->');
                this.props.getSportsData();

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: youre calling sportsdata not birddata

Comment: @jonathanHeindl in second file I am making a different api call so I am calling getSportsData, can you help me in fixing it

Comment: seeing only this I asume render is called once per frame so I suggest setting a boolean on ether it has been called before and only call it if it hasnt

Comment: @jonathanHeindl hey can you update in my code snippet, its so confusing :(