# Difference between componentDidUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps while creating new job

Tags: reactjs

I am confused with the character of these two lifecycle methods. `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillReceiveProps`. I am testing with two types :

1. existing task
2. new task

Check these two codes:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || (JSON.stringify(nextProps.locationData) != JSON.stringify(this.props.locationData))) {
            console.log(nextProps.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
            this.props.initLocationData(nextProps.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || (JSON.stringify(prevProps.locationData) != JSON.stringify(this.props.locationData)))) {
            this.props.initLocationData(this.props.locationData.locations.locationDetails);
        }
    }
```

for the existing task, both methods are giving an exact correct result. For the new task, `componentWillReceiveProps` is giving last saved result but `componentDidUpdate` is giving proper result. If anyone can explain it correctly

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386324/componentdidupdate-vs-componentwillreceiveprops-use-case-in-react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [componentDidUpdate vs componentWillReceiveProps use case in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386324/componentdidupdate-vs-componentwillreceiveprops-use-case-in-react)