# how to pass props to multi-level components in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi I am working on react recently, and I have a question here: so if we want to pass props to multi-level components, how to do it efficiently??

Say that I have three components, **Parent, Child, ChildOfChild**. I want to pass a props from **Parent to ChildOfChild**.

What I did is to use **componentWillReceiveProps** in Child and ChildOfChild.

like this:
Parent:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
// @ts-ignore
import Child from "./Child";


class Parent extends Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <Child filters={this.state.filters} />

        );
    }
}
export default () => {

    return (<Parent/>)
}
```

Child:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ChildOfChild from "./ChildOfChild";

class Child extends Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.filters !== this.props.filters) {
            this.setState({filters: nextProps.filters});
        }
    }


    public render() {
        return <ChildOfChild
            filters = {this.state.filters}
            uri = {this.state.uri}
            label = {this.state.label} />
    }
}

export default Child
```

and ChildOfChild:

```
import React from "react";
import {Component} from "react";

import * as _ from 'lodash';

import {makeStyles, createStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {BackstageTheme} from '@backstage/theme'


const useStyles = makeStyles<BackstageTheme>(() =>
    createStyles({
        someStyle: {
            position: 'relative',
        }
    }),
);

interface Props {
    filters?: any,
    label?: string,
    uri?: string
}

class ChildOfChild extends Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.filters !== this.props.filters) {
            this.fetchCountData(nextProps.filters);
        }

    }

    public componentDidMount() {

        this.fetchCountData(null);
    }

    public fetchCountData(filters) {
        if (filters != null && Object.keys(filters).length > 0) {
            // get data from api

        }
    }


    public render() {
        const popOverText = this.props.label;  // used somewhere
        const classes = this.props.classes;

        return (
            <p className={classes.someStyle}>
            {title}
            </p>
                
        );
    }
}

export default (props:Props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <ChildOfChild classes={classes} {...props}/>
    )
}
```

Also I tried "componentDidUpdate", very similar usage, but as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51313510/11650363  they are different.

**So I just want to ask how is my solution? any drawbacks??
any other good solutions to pass props to multi layers??**

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops). Just pass the props on through to the child's child, not need to store in local state of the middle component, and in fact, storing passed props into state is an anti-pattern in React.

Comment: @DrewReese get you elaborate a little bit, how to pass props without storing it in middle component, do you mean remove the middle component???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing passed props in local component state is anti-pattern in React, you should pass them on to children. [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) for all intents and purposes has been deprecated and shouldn't be used. For this you should implement the [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method and check the previous props/state to the current state/props value in order to issue any side-effects.

Parent

```
class Parent extends Component<any, any> {
  state = {
    filters: [],
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child filters={this.state.filters} />
    );
  }
}

export default Parent
```

Child

```
class Child extends Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ..... }
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <ChildOfChild
        filters={this.props.filters} // <-- pass from props
        uri={this.state.uri}
        label={this.state.label}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Child's Child

```
class ChildOfChild extends Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ....
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCountData(this.props.filters);
  }

  public componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (propProps.filters !== this.props.filters) { // <-- check if props updated
      this.fetchCountData(this.props.filters);
    }
  }

  public fetchCountData(filters) {
    if (filters != null && Object.keys(filters).length > 0) {
      // get data from api
    }
  }  

  public render() {
    const popOverText = this.props.label;
    const classes = this.props.classes;

    return (
      <p className={classes.someStyle}>
        {title}
      </p>      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! I am just confused why don't need ```componentDidUpdate```  in Child? I remember the change of props won't enforce component to re-render, right?

Comment: @HongliBu React components rerender when their state and/or props update, or when an ancestor component rerenders (i.e. it will rerender its subtree).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (if you're familiar with `functional component` in React). `React Context` is a library from React to control the global states in your app. The `states` can be variables or functions.

You can also use another global state management like [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) (you don't have to use `functional component` in your app).

Imagine if you have an app with this hierarchy.

[image]

For example, if want to access a state from `App` component in `Table Cell` component, it would exhaust your energy and time if you pass the props down manually from parent component to child component.

With `React Context` or `React Redux`, you can do it with a few line of codes.

Note: source of the image https://64.media.tumblr.com/bcfb43ecedb69f2ee8c0cae2b758ab35/tumblr_inline_ofcxnvTThG1rgj0aw_500.png